# codeigniter and adding stylesheets

Tags: css, codeigniter, directory-structure

I add a stylesheet to codeigniter:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Site Administrator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/administrator.css" type="text/css" ></link>

</head>
```

But the rules arent added. I go two directories up and go to the css.. The direction of the href is right.. I used the autocomplete feature in netbeans.. But why no rules are added to the page? is it codeigniters problem?

My rules in the stylesheet:

```
        #container
        {
           margin: 0px auto;
           width:50%;
           background-color: #99BC99;
        }

        #container:first-child
        {
           text-align: center;
        }

        #heading
        {

            text-align: right;

        }
        h2
        {
            float:right;
            margin-right: 130px;
        }
        a
        {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

My html:

```
<div id="container">
<h1>ממשק מנהל</h1>
<div id="heading">

      <h2>  
        <?php echo anchor('news/local/123', 'צור נושא', 'title="News title"'); ?>
            </h2>
        <h2>  
            <?php echo anchor('news/local/123', 'הוסף אמייל', 'title="News title"'); ?>
        </h2>
        <h2>  
            <?php echo anchor('news/local/123', 'שנה שם וסיסמה', 'title="News title"'); ?>
        </h2>

</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is what it gives me:

```
This is what it gives me:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/finance_site/index.php/css/administrator.css" />
```

Whenever, I do this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=site_url('css/administrator.css');?>" />
```

Alright, I got it, it is like this:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/finance_site/css/administrator.css" />
```

Is there a way to re-write it so it will be a relative link to code igniter...or at least more portable?

Comment: Your given information is too limited

Comment: How much information do you want?

Comment: What is the folder structure you are working with? Where does CodeIgniter and where does the CSS sit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/administrator.css`

Comment: True, it goes to page not found

Comment: @BlackFire27 changed my answer

Comment: Use the code above and Chrome page source to see there it points to figure out how path it should be

Comment: I do..but the system routes them differently..I want to make them relative..though

Comment: Ok do this trick `echo realpath('.');` this will show you where you are and help you find the relative path

Answer (score 2):

I tend to place things such as stylesheets, css, js, etc in /public.

You can then use `<?=site_url('public/css/administrator.css);?>` in the view.

Comment: Where is that public directory...do I need to create it?

Comment: See update..I arrived at the solution..but I want to make my application more portable..how do I re-write the solution in codeIgniter?

Comment: `<?=site_url('css/administrator.css');?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `/css/administrator.css` or `css/administrator.css`.

Comment: CodeIgniters structure.. to hard to explain, if you are unfamiliar with the struture

Comment: I'm very familiar with CI, but what I don't know is where you keep your CSS stuff.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS** - use the base tag, this sets a default target for all links

```
<base href="<?php echo base_url();?>" />
```

-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/some_file.css" />
```

**JS** - To pass the base_url to javascript if you need to make ajax requests you could use this before you include your external javascript files(s)

```
<script>
var BASE_URL = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
</script>
```